# Extract array elements to separate array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a program that extract every 3th element from array. So far i have made the basic array, but im stuck at extracting every 3th element into separate array. How can i do that?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int min = -100;
    int max = 100;

    int[] array = new int[201];
for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    array[i] = min + (int)(Math.random()*((max - min) + 1));
```

Comment: Check if it's divisible by 3, if it is then use it.

Comment: use mod, in java that is the `%` operator

Comment: With a `for` loop you can iterate through an array with whatever step you want. For instance    `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill in a new array (named `array2`) with every 3rd item from your array:

```
int[] array2 = new int[array.length / 3];
int k = 2;
for(int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    array2[j] = array[k];
    k += 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just make your for loop jump by three:

```
int[] newArray = new int[array.length / 3];
for (int i = 2 ; i < array.length ; i+=3) {
  newArray[i/3] = array[i];
}
```